# Data get duplicate in WPF DataGrid when I refresh it

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am new in C# programming. I have a `DataGrid` which gets data from a local database. When I perform any task on my data, I need to refresh the `DataGrid` to get new values in it. But unfortunately, every time I refresh the `DataGrid` I duplicate the values in it. Here is the code :

```
string query = ("select * from employee_data");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Here is the screen shot of `DataGrid` after update:

[Image of DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlVvH.png)

Comment: cleanup before adding new data: `dt.Clear()` before `sda.Fill(dt);`

Comment: Try call `dt.Clear();` before you call `  sda.Fill(dt);`

Comment: @ASh I am using syncfusion SfDataGrid and .clear() works to avoid duplicates on refresh, thanksssss alot man